# Avoid logout at Remote Desktop Sessions

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am not using a Terminal Server and thus I have no Remote Desktop Services installed since it needs a license which I haven't got. I want to know whether there is another way to solve my following problem:

I have an application which needs to run on the host os (Windows Server 2012 Standard R2) directly and not in a VM. The problem is that once I leave the RDP aka user logs out my application will crash because it uses GPU functions. So I try to find a way how I can keep those sessions all the time active (even when I am not connected anymore).

I know it's a strange problem, but i hope you can help me.

Comment: `.1.` What you're doing is probably a violation of the EULA. `2.` Don't log out of the session, just disconnect from it.

Comment: Disconnecting is what I do and this is what my application crashes so I need to be logged in all the time. Why is it violation of the EULA exactly ?

Comment: `1.` You stated `The problem is that once I leave the RDP aka user logs out` so I took that to mean that you were logging out. `2.` Accessing an RDS session for the purpose of running an application is a violation of the EULA because unless you install the RDS role and the RDS License role and purchase RDS CAL's then you may only connect to the server via RDS for the purpose of administering the server, not for the purpose of running applications in that RDS session.

Comment: I would only join the RDP session if I could, since I am actually only accessing it to administer it, but my application which I wish to run crashes when I leave the server and this would just be a trick to avoid a application crash. Problem is that it is accessing the GPU thats why it is crashing. Under those circumstances its not an violation of the EULA I think. However do you have an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: If you're connecting to the server via RDS for any purpose other than administering the server it is a violation of the EULA. The EULA is not open to your interpretation.